# How to defer function with parameters in Meteor?

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, meteor

I know about `Meteor.defer()` and would like to use it in a webservice response, since the computation can be done after sending the response back.

However my function needs a parameter, and `Meteor.defer()` only receives a function name, no parameters.

I tried `_defer` from [underscore.js](http://underscorejs.org/), but since this is server side code, I got an error telling that Meteor code should always run inside a fiber.

What are my options?

Answer (score 3):

You could use `.bind` to pre-supply parameters for function:

```
function test(a, b) {
  console.log(a, b);
}

Meteor.methods({
  test() {
    const testWithParam12 = test.bind(undefined, 1, 2);
    Meteor.defer(testWithParam12);
  }
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Just pass an anonymous function to `Meteor.defer`:

```
var a = 1;

var myFunction = function (param) { 
    //... do something 
};

Meteor.defer(function () {
    myFunction(a);
});
```